# Opening of modal requiring to be opened two times

Tags: javascript, html

In my website I have a problem with my modal. It is supposed to be triggered by an icon appearing close to the embed tags. Although it works to activate the modal, it just displays the modal-content without anything in it; after closing the modal and making a second click on the openModal() function the wanted embed file is displayed. Then when clicking another document it displays the preceding document until closed and clicked again. Why is this happening and what should I do to fix it?

HTML (but with only one embed) :

```
<div class = "overlay-cont">
     <embed src="link-to-pdf.pdf" > 
     <div class = "overlay">
         <img class = "enlarge-icon" src = "arrow-icon.svg" onclick ="openModal(0)"> 
     </div>
</div>

<div id = "myModal" class = "modal">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
   <div class="modal-content">
      <embed id = "currentDoc">
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var doc = document.getElementsByTagName("EMBED");

function openModal(n){
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("currentDoc").src = doc[n].src;

}

function closeModal(){
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a static embed element and giving it dynamic src attribute value, generate dynamic embed element every time you show the modal and remove it every time you close the modal.

```js
var doc = document.getElementsByTagName("EMBED");

        function openModal(n) {
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
            modal.style.display = "block";
            var node = document.createElement("embed");
            var src_attr = document.createAttribute("src");
            src_attr.value = doc[n].src;
            node.setAttributeNode(src_attr);
            modal.appendChild(node);

        }

        function closeModal() {
            var e = document.querySelectorAll("embed")[1];
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
            document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none"
        }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay-cont">
        <embed src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <div class="overlay">
            <img class="enlarge-icon" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d" onclick="openModal(0)">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While it's great that the the specified document gets opened with only one click, there's now a problem with each document remaining in the modal; it seems that the remove() method doesn't work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You can also try removeChild() method. Please have a look at the modified code. You can also refer :https://gomakethings.com/removing-an-element-from-the-dom-with-vanilla-js/